# Unity3D Camera Switching on trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I would really appreciate help on getting camera switching working in my game. The point is that the game starts, the player sees the ball(it's kind of the basic rolling a ball game), starts moving up and they need to go up again but in another direction, so i need the camera to be the way that they see what they're doing. I got the camera placements right, but I can't figure out how to script it the way that it would work correctly. I got it working once, but I messed something up and can't get it to work again.

This is the code so far, that I have put together from my searches:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera front_camera;//assign your main camera here
    public Camera back_camera;//assign your top camera here

    void Start()
    {
        front_camera.enabled = true;
        back_camera.enabled = false;
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Pickup")
        {
            front_camera.enabled = false;
            back_camera.enabled = true;
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.name == "Ground")
        {
            front_camera.enabled = true;
            back_camera.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I can't figure out how to script it the way that it would work correctly"_. How is it working now?

Comment: Are you sure all the prerequisites of collision detection are satisifed? (Rigidbody on one object at least, colliders on both, one collider with `isTrigger` checked, and the script on the desired collider)

Comment: do both cameras have the maincamera tag?

Comment: @umairM it's not working

Comment: @Hellium Yes, I have done them all. The little pick up object that the ball needs to pick up/collide with to trigger the camera switch, but it's not doing that.

Comment: I would suggest using [Tag comparison](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EA54-vfLkUI) instead of names

Comment: Try using `Debug.Log("<your text>")` to see what's going on.

Comment: Using the Debug.Log("<your text>") I found out that this piece of code: void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
  if (other.gameObject.name == "Pickup") {
   front_camera.enabled = false;
   back_camera.enabled = true;

is being run right from the start, and when collides with the Pickup, it won't trigger anything.

Comment: make sure your script is not disabling.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan how do I do that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your script is **disabling (maybe its attache to camera)** therefore, you are getting the problem. Make ensure that **CameraSwitch** is not disabling otherwise there is no problem with code.

Alternatively you can attach your camera switch script to the ball and placed two collider which cover front and back camera area respectively. something like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code from **Unity Scripting Manual** and its working fine.

Please Look into this [Camera.main Scripting Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html)

Comment: I want the camera switching to be triggered on collision not that a button has to be pressed and that triggers it. Thanks tho!